# Modifying cython instance read-only properties in runtime

Tags: python, runtime, grpc, cython

I am using python aio grpc implementation, which is using `cython`. One of `grpc` features is `interceptor`, this is a class which get the request before the grpc's Server instance, and can modify the requests as it wants.

The proper way to use `interceptors` is to pass them to the `Server` constructor on `__init__`.

I need to do so in **runtime**, that means that I need to modify the `server._interceptors` list after the instance is already created.

it's working perfect when using pure-python implementations, but not when using Cython.

This is the [cython AioServer implementation](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/ffafac3ce8ea53cbceffb53063070be813edc31f/src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/_cygrpc/aio/server.pyx.pxi#L875).

when trying to access `_interceptors` field, I get `'grpc._cython.cygrpc.AioServer' object has no attribute 'interceptors'`.
When trying to replace any function, I get - `'grpc._cython.cygrpc.AioServer' object attribute '_request_call' is read-only`.

is there anyway to modify cython implemented instances on runtime ? or it's just not possible ? I want to modify the property or monkey patch some function which will modify the property, but the important part is that should happen on RUNTIME.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't really "read only" - it's simply inaccessible from Python, since no-one has asked Cython to generate accessor functions for that attribute (either read-write or read-only).  However, you can access it from Cython when the type is known. For example (in Cython):

```
def change_interceptors(AioServer server, new_interceptors):
    server._interceptors = new_interceptors
```

So, if you're prepared to write Cython code then you can modify this property. If you aren't then you can't.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Just to be sure that I got you right - I can modify these value only if I add a setter in the original cython source code, right? it's not possible to do so in python runtime?

Comment: No. You can write your own separate Cython module and write a function to set it from there. But it does need Cython so you can't do it from the Python runtime alone